# How can I access the superclass value of a getter in a subclass?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, overriding, typescript

Accessing the `super` value of a `getter` in a derived class doesn't seem to work:

```
class Foo {
    private _message:string = "Hello,";

    public get Message():string {
        return this._message;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public get Message():string {
        return super.Message + " World";
    }   
}

var snafu:Bar = new Bar();
document.write(snafu.Message);

// Expected: "Hello, World"
// Actual: "undefined World"
```

How can I correctly override a `getter` and make use of the `super` value?

Comment: This is just one of many "gotchas" in TypeScript inheritance. TS looks so much like C# that it fools you into thinking that it acts like C# too. See http://blog.wouldbetheologian.com/2012/11/various-typescript-weirdnesses.html for several more :-(.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not necessarily endorsing that you continue with this approach, but...

```
class Bar extends Foo {
    public get Message():string {
        return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Foo.prototype, 'Message').get.apply(this) +  ' World';
    }   
}
```

Prototypal inheritance doesn't make this particularly straightforward.

Comment: Thanks. I have an external constraint in the form of a specific model (of cascading print styles) that uses overridden properties heavily - this approach at least lets me work with it in TS.